# How to calculate $Ri^!$?

Tags: homological-algebra, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology, derived-functors

Given a locally compact (Hausdorff) space $X$ and an open subset $U\subseteq X$ with complement $Z=X\setminus U$. Denote $i\colon Z\to X$ and $j\colon U\to X$ canonical inclusions. $j_*\colon\mathbf{Sh}(U)\to\mathbf{Sh}(X)$ is the direct image, and $i^!\colon\mathbf{Sh}(X)\to\mathbf{Sh}(Z)$ is the exceptional inverse image. Given a sheaf $\mathcal F$ on $X$, I want to know how to calculate $Ri^!(\mathcal F)$, where $Ri^!\colon\mathbf D(X)\to\mathbf D(Z)$ is the right derived functor of $i^!$. I'm most interested in the special case when $\mathcal F=M$ is a constant sheaf.

The higher direct image $Rj_*$ is more manageable: choose an injective resolution $\mathcal G\to\mathcal I^\bullet$ on $U$, we have $R^mj_*(\mathcal G)=H^m(j_*(\mathcal I^\bullet))$, which is associated to presheaf $$V\mapsto H^m\Gamma(V,j_*(\mathcal I^\bullet))=H^m\Gamma(j^{-1}(V),\mathcal I^\bullet)=H^m(j^{-1}(V),\mathcal G)$$
Moreover, the complex $Rj_*$ could be determined stalk-wise: for $x\in X$, denote $i_x\colon\{x\}\to X$ the inclusion,
$$i_x^{-1}Rj_*(\mathcal G)^\bullet=i_x^{-1}j_*(\mathcal I^\bullet)=\varinjlim_{V\ni x}\Gamma(V,j_*(\mathcal I^\bullet))=\varinjlim_{V\ni x}\Gamma(f^{-1}(V),\mathcal I^\bullet)=\varinjlim_{V\ni x}R\Gamma(f^{-1}(U),\mathcal G)^\bullet$$
The same trick will lead to a reduction of $R^mi^!(\mathcal F)$ to the sheaf associated to $V\mapsto\operatorname{Ext}^m(i_*(\mathbb Z_V),\mathcal F)$, but the later one doesn't seem computable.

Take the simplest case, if $X$ is a differentiable manifold of dimension $n$ and $Z$ is a point, $\mathcal F=\mathbb Z$ is a constant sheaf. I cannot see how the formula above leads to anything easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main tools at your disposal are duality and the localization triangles.

I come from algebraic geometry where everything is orientable and there is a factor 2 between dimension and cohomological degree, so I hope I will not make any mistakes.

The localization triangles are the following :
$$ i_*Ri^!\longrightarrow 1\longrightarrow Rj_*j^{-1}\overset{+1}\longrightarrow$$
The morphisms being the counit and the unit of adjunction. Moreover, the cone of $1\rightarrow Rj_*j^{-1}$ is unique up to unique isomorphism in this case (this is because it has support on $Z$ and there are no morphism from a complex with support on $Z$ and a complex of the form $Rj_*C$). Thus, the object $i_*Ri^!C$ is uniquely determined by $C\rightarrow Rj_*j^{-1}C$. Applying $i^{-1}$ on the left gives
$$ Ri^!\longrightarrow i^{-1}\longrightarrow i^{-1}Rj_*j^{-1}\overset{+1}\longrightarrow$$

These triangles give rise to long exact sequences which might give you some informations about $Ri^!$.

For example, if $X$ is a nice (paracompact and locally contractible) topological space and $Z=\{x\}$ a point, then the first triangle give rise to the long exact sequence in cohomology
$$H^n(X,X\setminus\{x\})\longrightarrow H^n(X)\longrightarrow H^n(X\setminus\{x\})\longrightarrow H^{n+1}$$

The first group is indeed $H^n(Ri^!\mathbb{Z})$. Of course, you can replace $X$ by any neighborhood of $x$. You can even go to the limit, this is essentially what gives the second distinguished triangle.

For example, if $X$ is a manifold of dimension $n$, replacing $X$ by an open ball around $x$, you get $Ri^!\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}[-n]$.

Another example : if $x$ is a singular point in a surface which look locally like the union of two planes in $\mathbb{R}^4$ having a single point of intersection, then $Ri^!\mathbb{Z}\simeq\mathbb{Z}[-1]\oplus\mathbb{Z}[-2]\oplus\mathbb{Z}[-2]$.

The equality $Ri^!\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}[-n]$ (when $Z$ is a point in a manifold) also follows from Poincaré duality. More generally, if $Z$ is an orientable submanifold of codimension $c$ in a manifold $X$ of dimension $n$. Assume moreover that $Z$ has an orientable tubular neighborhood in $X$, then $Ri^!\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}[-c]$. Indeed, replace $X$ by the tubular neighborhood and let $p:X\rightarrow\{*\}$ be the projection. Then $Rp^!\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}[n]$ by Poincaré duality. Similarly, $Ri^!Rp^!\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}[n-c]$. So $Ri^!\mathbb{Z}[n]=\mathbb{Z}[n-c]$, hence the result.

Comment: A quick question: how to prove the triangle you've mentioned is distinguished? I saw proofs via injective resolution (first showing that the short sequence is left exact and with assumption that the sheaf is injective the short sequence becoming exact). This works for the bounded case. For unbounded derived categories of Grothendieck categories, we have homotopically injective complexes, but I don't know whether each degree is injective.

Comment: @FrankScience I am afraid I don't know for the unbounded case. I will have to think about it. In fact, I usually define $Ri^!$ using this triangle. I am not sure that the following works but if you proceed by defining $Ri^!$ via the triangle, you have $H^0(Ri^!\mathcal{F})=i^!\mathcal{F}$ using the long exact sequence and the definition of the latter. Using again the long exact sequence, you can see that $H^n(Ri^!\mathcal{I})$ vanishes on injective for $n>0$ and so $H^n(Ri^!\mathcal{F})$ are indeed the derived functors of $i^!$. Can you use this to prove it is also true for the complexes ?

Comment: I forgot to note that here we don't need the result of the totally unbounded case. But according to [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/homotopically+injective+object), any complex is quesi-isomorphic to a complex which is both K-injective and injective, so the original proof works, interesting.